# Visual C++ link generated objs from referenced project

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I have multiple **native C++** projects, one of them is a dll project, and I want to test it.

The problem is that the generated **.lib** file only contains the definitions for the public interface of the dll, but I would like to test the projects internals.

Since referencing the project does not work (it only works for static libraries) is there a way to add the the generated objs directly in my testing project ?

Also I know that I could include all the source code files in the referenced project. But is there a way to do this considering that the referenced project might change. I would like a method that does not force me to mange each file manually.

I have done some research and I found some answers like in this question:
[Reusing object files in Visual Studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261518/reusing-object-files-in-visual-studio-2005)
but since I have many small classes exposing all the classes is a bit to tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can set a **Pre Link Event** in the **Build Event** menu.

This allows me to use the following command:

```
lib -out:"../Debug/tempAllDllObjects.lib" "../MyDLLProject/Debug/*.obj"
```

now, even if my project is a DLL project I have an additional **.lib** file that contains all the objects in my project. All I have to do is reference the newly created lib file. This way I can link with all the objects in my DLL project even if they are not in the public interface.

As a note the command can also be set on the **DLL project** as a **Postbuild Event** this will increase the efficiency since now the **lib** file is only generated when changes occur.

Comment: You can even use wildcards like *.obj in the Additional Linker Inputs.